# Recurrent replacement using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, loops

I have a word (MODEL 1) in my file 20 times interspersed by lines of text. I want to replace it with the frequency number of occurrence e.g. MODEL 1 and then when it occurs again then MODEL 2 and then MODEL 3 and so on so forth.

However my loop gets stuck at the first round and not looping till it has replaced all of words.

Can any one tell me what I have been missing out. Any help would be much appreciated.

The code is listed below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $file = 'test.text';
open (my $fh, $file);

while (my $row = <$fh>) { 

    chomp $row;
    if (($row) =~ /^MODEL 1/){

        $i = 1;
        $row =~ s/^MODEL 1/MODEL $i/g;
        $i++;   
    }

    print "$row\n";
}
```

Comment: It's MODEL 1 at the beginning of the line? If not, remove the ^ char

Comment: Will there be more than one MODEL 1 per line?

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your counter variable outside of the loop.

As a simplification, use `s///e` to match and replace in a single step:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'test.text';

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my $counter = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    s/^MODEL \K1/++$counter/e;

    print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: i'd add a `g` flag, since the OP does have one.

Comment: Yes, his regex does have a /g.   However, it is also anchored to the start of the line.  Therefore there can only be 1 match.

Comment: oh, slight oversight on my side, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Move `$i = 1` initialization to above `while` loop

```
$i = 1;
while (my $row = <$fh>) { chomp $row;
  ...
}
```

You're resetting it back to for every line, so there won't be any change at all.

Comment: If you're using the OP's regex, this doesn't work for multiple replacements on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a counter in the replacement pattern itself with the e modifier:

```
my $i=1;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    $row =~ s/MODEL \K1/$i++/ge
    print "$row\n";
}
```